# De que forma posso matar um processo como usuário administrador do windows?

Tags: cmd

Estou com a porta 8080 sendo usando por um processo misterioso.
usei o comando

> taskkill -f -im 2412

E recebo a mensagem:

> ERRO: o processo com PID 2412 não pôde ser finalizado. Razão: Acesso
>   negado.

Comment: Execute o o cmd como administrador

Comment: Erro de privilegio, alguns processos necessitam ter nivel elevado

Comment: De que forma digito o nome do usuairo e senha ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha só, para matar certos processos do Windows o mesmo requisita que o nível do usuário seja *administrativo*, no caso, que você seja um **Administrador**

Para verificar se a sua conta tem permissões administrativas você deve fazer pequenos passos:

1. Aperte as teclas **WIN+R** para abrir a janela **Executar**
2. Digite no campo o seguinte: **control userpasswords2**

E então abrirá uma janela listando os usuários locais e em rede que estão registrados no seu computador. Encontre o seu nome e verifique se ao lado você pertence ao grupo de **Administradores**.

Então você abre o menu Iniciar e pesquisa por CMD, o único retorno que o windows irá dar a você será do *cmd.exe*. E então com o botão direito do mouse em cima dele, você seleciona a opção **Executar como Administador**.

E então você manda executar o seu código.

> Se na janela **control userpasswords2** você não estiver com níveis administrativos, ou você deve pedir para o **administrado**r do computador acesso, ou se somente você usa a máquina, você deve criar um novo usuário administrativo (pois o seu nível não deveria estar como **Usuário Padrão**) para conseguir alterar o seu usuário como **Administrador**.

Há também chances de o processo estar sendo usado por outro (no qual obriga a fechar o que está usando-o primeiro) ou o windows não deixa você encerrar pois é um componente que está mantendo ele em execução.

Answer (score 1):

Abra o `cmd` como Administrador e digite:

tasklist vai mostrar os processos

```
  tasklist
```

para finalizar o processo digite :

```
 taskkill /f /im  exemplo.exe
```

Comment: de que forma adiciono o nome do administrador e a senha ?

Comment: você deve abrir o cmd como administrador